# Convert assembly instruction set to16-bit numbers

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, simulator, instruction-encoding

Below I have a question that I got, but I'm struggling to figure out how to go about doing it. Any advice or help is much appreciated.

Below is the instruction set for a machine:

> 0x00   halt -- Terminate program
>
> 0x01   nop  -- Do nothing
>
> 0x02   li   -- Load Immediate: li R1 0x00000000
> Load 0x00000000 into R1
>
> 0x03   lw   -- Load Word: lw R1 R2
> Load the contents of the memory location
> pointed to by R2 into R1
>
> 0x04   sw   -- Store Word: sw R1 R2
> Store the contents of R2 in the memory
> location pointed to by R1
>
> 0x05   add  -- Add: add R3 R1 R2
> Add R1 to R2 and store the result in R3
>
> 0x06   sub  -- Subtract: sub R3 R1 R2
> Subtract R2 from R1 and store the result in R3
>
> 0x07   mult -- Multiply: mult R3 R1 R2
> Multiply R1 by R2 and store the result in R3
>
> 0x08   div  -- Divide: div R3 R1 R2
> Divide R1 by R2 and store the result in R3
>
> 0x09   j    -- Unconditional Jump: j 0x00000000
> Jump to memory location 0x00000000
>
> 0x0A   jr   -- Unconditional Jump (Register): jr R1
> Jump to memory location stored in R1
>
> 0x0B   beq  -- Branch if Equal: bne R1 R2 R3
> Branch to memory location stored in R3
> if R1 and R2 are equal
>
> 0x0C   bne  -- Branch if Not Equal: beq R1 R2 R3
> Branch to memory location stored in R3
> if R1 and R2 are not equal
>
> 0x0D   inc  -- Increment Register: inc R1
> Increment R1
>
> 0x0E   dec  -- Decrement Register: dec R1
> Decrement R1
>
> It has five registers and 64K of memory in a 32-bit address space,
> that is 0x00000000–0x0000FFFF. The five registers consist of three
> general purpose (R1, R2, R3); and two special purpose, a program
> counter (instruction pointer) register (PC), and a conditional
> register (COND) that stores conditional flags which provide
> information about the most recently executed calculation allowing
> programs to check logical conditions.
>
> Each instruction is encoded in a half word (16 bits) in little endian.
> The first 4 bits (half byte) contain the instruction number, which can
> be anything from 0x0 to 0xE, while the second, third and fourth
> half-bytes (4 bit sections) contain register numbers. (Note: For some
> instructions like li the remainder of the 8 bits after the instruction
> number and the register number contain an 8 bit immediate value.)
> Write an assembler for the instruction set that takes a text assembly
> program written for the above instruction set and produces the program
> as a set of 16-bit numbers. Basically, the task is to encode the text
> of the assembly into the bytecode format.
>
> Write a simulator for the machine that will take the output of the
> assembler and execute it, correctly. For example, you should be able
> to run the following program:
>
> ```
> ; a simple counter program.
> li R1 0x00000000
> ; end
> li R2 0x0000FFFF
> ; memory location of loop start
> li R3 loop
> loop:
>  ; store the contents of R1 at the memory location pointed by R1
>  sw R1 R1
>  ; increment the counter
>  inc R1
>  ; loop if the counter hasn't yet reached the end
>  bne R1 R2 R3
>  ; end program
>  halt
> ```
>
> Programs should be loaded from 0x0000CFFF to the end of memory so that
> any memory before that is usable by the programmer. The simulator
> should log the register values after every cycle (upon execution of
> every instruction).

I haven't tried much since I've never met such a question before.

Comment: SO helps with specific questions, so you should to work on the design then ask  questions  about specific parts of it like "how do I do X, this is what I've tried so far".  Your course materials and lectures should have covered the ideas that you need to come up with the design.  If there are chat rooms, study groups, discussion groups those can help too.

Comment: Also, working through the design steps will help you learn to write new apps.  If you find some existing design and copy it or ask an AI to write it for you, you'll miss out on the learning process that is the point of the course.

Comment: This is a Q&A website; you're supposed to ask a question.  If you simply cite the homework problem statement, we don't know what you know and what you don't know and where you're stuck.  Obviously, you're not asking for us to do the assignment for you so, what do you want to know?

Comment: fwiw, 0x00000000–0x0000FFFF is a 16-bit address space.

Comment: Get ahold of an example, to study it; suggest a 3 register instruction like `add R1 R2 R3`.  You'll need to know the add opcode, which is given as 5, then need to know how registers are encoded (and their ordering), but let's say that R1 =1 and R2 = 2 and R3 = 3 (why not?) and that they are ordered left to right, then that add is 5 1 2 3, or 0x5123 as a 16-bit instruction.  Do the rest like that and Bob's your uncle.  Just need to tease out and verify the assumptions such as I've stated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is often called a bitfield. It helps to think of the numbers you were given in terms of binary. Let's look at `li R3, 0x000000FF` for example.

From your table, `li` has an encoding of `02`. In binary, this is `0010`. (I used four digits since the instruction size is 16 bits total, in 4 bit sections.)

```
opcode   register   immediate
0010     ????       ????     ????
```

Since we're using `R3` the next 4 bits get their own encoding. (It's kind of weird that we don't start with `R0` but oh well.) I'll pretend that `R1` is encoded as `0001`, `R2` as `0010`, and `R3` as `0011`.

```
opcode   register   immediate
0010     0011       ????     ????
```

And now for the immediate. `0xFF` in binary is `11111111` so we just put that in the last 8 bits.

```
opcode   register   immediate
0010     0011       1111     1111
```

Thus, we get the following 2 bytes `00100011 11111111`, or in hex, `23FF`.

(P.S. I'm assuming when you said "first four bits" you're referring to the most-significant (leftmost) bits.)